# Writing a contact's photo into a vcf file, android

Tags: java, android, android-contacts, vcf-vcard

I am using a code in which a list of all contacts is shown. When I select a contact from the list, details of the contact are shown and saved in a .vcf file (in proper vcard format), working fine. when I select a contact which has a photo as well, it shows the photo in imageView, but I don't know how to write the photo in vcf file.
I have used these lines,

```
Uri photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,Integer.parseInt(item));
Bitmap photoBitmap;
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
InputStream is = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, photoUri);
photoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photoBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , bos);
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(bitmapdata,Base64.DEFAULT);

String content = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\nCLASS:PUBLIC\nPRODID:-//class_vcard from  TroyWolf.com//NONSGML Version 1//EN\nFN:"+contactName+"\nTEL;TYPE=cell,voice:"+number+"\nPHOTO;TYPE=JPEG;ENCODING=BASE64:"+imageEncoded+"\nTZ:+0000\nEND:VCARD";
```

But I am getting error while reading the contact("Failed to parse vCard for unexpected reason, Invalid line:")
Can anyone please help me solve the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the value of the `ENCODING` parameter from `BASE64` to `B`.  `B` is the correct value to use in 3.0 vCards.

Also, the correct newline sequence for vCards is `\r\n`, not `\n`.

You might be interested in using a vCard library to generate your vCard.  [ez-vcard](http://code.google.com/p/ez-vcard) is one such library (disclaimer: I am the author).

```
VCard vcard = new VCard();
vcard.setClassification("PUBLIC");
vcard.setProdId("-//class_vcard from  TroyWolf.com//NONSGML Version 1//EN");
vcard.setFormattedName(contactName);

TelephoneType tel = vcard.addTelephoneNumber(number);
tel.addType(TelephoneTypeParameter.CELL);
tel.addType(TelephoneTypeParameter.VOICE);

PhotoType photo = new PhotoType(bitmapdata, ImageTypeParameter.JPEG);
vcard.addPhoto(photo);

vcard.setTimezone(new TimezoneType(0, 0));

String content = Ezvcard.write(vcard).version(VCardVersion.V3_0).prodId(false).go();
```

Comment: Can I use ez-vcard library for android as well? It is giving me exception (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ezvcard.VCard). I have used ez-vcard-0.7.3.jar in the project.
Also, can you please tell me what is 'B'? as, you have told me to use B instead of Base64!

Comment: I don't know for sure if you can use ez-vcard for android.  I would think that you could, since ez-vcard is a Java library.  `B` has the same meaning as `BASE64`.  They just decided to use `B` in version 3.0 for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really late post, but I couldn't find any working solution on StackOverflow without using the library, so I thought it would be good to share my findings.

Changing the encoding parameter and correcting a newline sequence weren't enough to construct .vcf file with a photo. I also had to remove the line breaks after encoding to base64.

Sample code to convert Uri to base64 format (replace imageStream initialization as needed).

```
// string you can use to write to vcf file (3.0 vCards)
String.format("PHOTO;ENCODING=B;TYPE=JPEG: ,%s\r\n", convertUriToBase64(context, photoUri));

private String convertUriToBase64(Context context, String photoUri) {
    InputStream imageStream = null;
    try {
        imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(photoUri));

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
    byte[] bitmapData = bos.toByteArray();
    // line break has to be removed, so it is on the same line as PHOTO
    return Base64.encodeToString(bitmapData, Base64.DEFAULT).replaceAll("\n", "");
}
```

Comment: Lack of code and explanation

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get a photo to send as part of the vCard...
Important things to consider:

1) Equipment: ZTE Axon 7 running Android 6.01

2) Couldn't get vCard 3.0 or 4.0 to function properly, could only use vCard 2.1

```
File vcfFile = new File(DisplayContactActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "generated.vcf");
                    try
                    {
                        /**Only Version 2.1 worked for me with or without PHOTO**/
                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(vcfFile);
                        fw.write("BEGIN:VCARD\r\n");
                        fw.write("VERSION:2.1\r\n");

                        fw.write("FN:" + "Contact 7" + "\r\n");

                        /*Getting the name of the File as I had saved it*/
                        String file_name = ("current_contact_image" + CONTACT_ID);

                        /*Get the bitmap that we stored in a File*/
                        Bitmap bitmap = getContactImage(file_name);

                        /*Convert bitmap to Base64*/
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
                        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                        String image_encoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

                        /*Write the encoded version of image to vCard 2.1, NOTICE that no determining whether the image is GIF or JPEG is needed*/   
                        fw.write("PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64:" + image_encoded + "\r\n");

                        /*Write some other stuff to the vCard also just trying to give whoever needs this a starting point*/  
                        fw.write("TEL;Primary:" + "(586) 268-3437" + "\r\n");
                        fw.write("TEL;OTHER:" + "(313) 313-4545" + "\r\n");

                        fw.write("ADR;OTHER:" + "12345 AnyLane Dr." + "\r\n");
                        fw.write("ADR;OTHER:" + "54321 AnyPlace Av." + "\r\n");

                        fw.write("EMAIL;OTHER:" + "email@yahoo.com" + "\r\n");
                        fw.write("EMAIL;OTHER:" + "email@wowway.com" + "\r\n");

                        fw.write("END:VCARD\r\n");
                        fw.close();

                        Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(vcfFile), "text/x-vcard");
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
                    }

public Bitmap getContactImage(String file_name)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Running getContactImage() with file name: " + file_name);

    Bitmap thumbnail = null;
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    try
    {
        File filePath = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(file_name);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
    }
    catch (Exception e) //Use scaled_bitmap_for_storage instead of the current_contact_image file name
    {
        /*Error getting user-selected image, set boolean to get default image*/
        Log.i(TAG, "Exception while running getContactImage() for file name: " + file_name + " with error message: " + e);
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    return thumbnail;
}
```